# What's the difference between Refresh, Update and Repaint?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I don't know which of those three methods suits me most. They all work for me. Does anyone know the difference between Refresh, Update and Repaint?

Comment: To you and the two people who up-voted this so far: I know that opening the Delphi help from the IDE is a bit slow, but it should still be faster than asking on SO and waiting for answers. Answers that can hardly do anything but quoting from the help.

Comment: Searching the online documentation, with Google is also another option.  http://docs.codegear.com/

Comment: Embarcadero help is notorious for its "high quality packed with informations". I understand ГошУ that he better asked here on SO.

Comment: It is faster to Google and end up on SO, than to read the help.

Comment: @truthseeker Please add an answer then. All the answers are docs lifts. This question has no value in my view.

Comment: @YeeLikeKram Only if you don't know how to use the documentation

Comment: @David Heffernan Disagree. Google has more intelligent search than most docs (including Embarcadero's). And docs, while obviously a good start, are often limited for lack of detail. SO has the benefit of user discussion. So no, just blandly saying RTFM doesn't necessarily help.

Comment: @David Of course. Discussing Invalidate is useful, and its discussion stems from the original question. I said Google and end up on SO since it's one of the first hits. I'm not changing my tune at all.

Comment: @Yee There is no discussion. Just a wishy washy statement that conveys no insight.

Comment: @David It mentions another method, which actually quite useful.

Comment: @Yee So do the doc links. Nobody says that Repaint = Refresh and that both = Invalidate + Update.

Comment: @Bizmarck: "It is faster to Google and end up on SO, than to read the help." Yes, but if you read the help, you don't have to wait for other people to answer. So googling SO and other places for an answer makes sense. *Asking* a question about what can easily be found in the help does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @mghie - The help will not make a comparison between the 3 functions (or 4 because he missed Invalidate)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the online documentation:

[Refresh](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Refresh.html) - Repaints the control on the screen.

> Call Refresh method to repaint the
> control immediately. Refresh calls the
> Repaint method. Use the Refresh and
> Repaint methods interchangeably.

[Repaint](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Repaint.html) - Forces the control to repaint its image on the screen.

> Call Repaint to force the control to
> repaint its image immediately. If the
> ControlStyle property includes
> csOpaque, the control paints itself
> directly. Otherwise, the Repaint
> method calls the Invalidate method and
> then the Update method so that any
> visible portions of controls beneath
> the control will be repainted as well.

[Update](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Update.html) - Processes any pending paint messages immediately.

> Call Update to force the control to be
> repainted before any more, possibly
> time-consuming, processing takes
> place. Use Update to provide immediate
> feedback to the user that cannot wait
> for the Windows paint message to
> arrive.
>
> Update does not invalidate the
> control, but simply forces a repaint
> of any regions that have already been
> invalidated. Call Repaint instead to
> invalidate the control as well.

Answer (score 40):

Your question is already answered, but if you need good performance and less flicker you should call Invalidate instead. It allows Windows to optimize the painting process.

[Invalidate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Invalidate.html) - Completely repaint control.

> Use Invalidate when the entire control
>   needs to be repainted. When more than
>   one region within the control needs
>   repainting, Invalidate will cause the
>   entire window to be repainted in a
>   single pass, avoiding flicker caused
>   by redundant repaints. There is no
>   performance penalty for calling
>   Invalidate multiple times before the
>   control is actually repainted.

Answer (score 4):

Per an older (CBuilder 6) VCL reference:

**Invalidate**  "Invalidate informs a control that its entire surface needs to be repainted. Calling Invalidate can prevent flicker caused by a series of partial repaints. There is no performance penalty for calling Invalidate multiple times before the control is actually repainted".

The actual repaint does not occur until the control is updated. To force an immediate repaint, call Repaint instead.

**Repaint** "TWinControl::Repaint calls the Invalidate method and then the Update method to repaint the control" (slight paraphrase).

(Sadly, the older reference is better and more complete than the newer reference I have (CBuilder 2007).