# One-line procedure do not work in Lazarus (Object Pascal)

Tags: compiler-construction, lazarus

I have an event - onClickButton where is only one line:

```
Button1.Caption:="ABC";
```

it isn't working ok - No effect after clicking on the button. When I insert another new line, for instance:

```
if x=10 then exit; //x=0 and exit doesn't invoke;
Button1.Caption:="ABC";
```

It works (caption on the button changed).

Any recompilation, building doesn't work. I other time or on other computer it works in both situations.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: What you're describing would be a blocking issue, which would never allow the compiler to be released to public. In other words, this must work. You must have a mistake in your code somewhere. Use debugger to see the real value of the `x` variable. Also always try to post the real code, not just fake pieces.

Comment: I don't have possibility take real unit code (I can not access at the moment to computer with presented problem) but It looks like I presented. The problem is not in line with "exit" - In this can be different code line - without corelation with button1.caption (I tried several) and only if one line was before line Button.Caption:='ABC" the last one worked ok. This unit (for Form) was simple - only with this events procedure - nothing else.

Comment: Ones I hade problem with similar events procedure where were two local variables a and b. I have assigned  values a=1 and b=2 and multiply p=a*b; When I use debugger I saw p=2 but when put it to edit.text=inttostr(p) - there was 1. I copy the same project to other computer - it was working ok. Therefore I don't understand where is problem. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Maybe you missed something `if x=10 then exit; //x=0 and exit doesn't invoke;` It sounds as the correct behavior: code says x=10 and comment says x=0

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes system didn't notice thaht something has chanhed and should be repainted. Have your tried calling `refresh`, `repaint` or `update` method on button or on whole application? There is nice explanation of this methods: [What's the difference between Refresh, Update and Repaint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251009/whats-the-difference-between-refresh-update-repaint)